# How can i check if a page is published?

Tags: publishing, 2009, tom.net

I want to check if a page is published or not.

```
TDSItems listPage = SGroup.GetItems(ItemType.ItemTypePage);

foreach (Page newPage in listPage)
{
    tcm = newPage.Info.ID;
}
```

I can see info properties but i don't know where I can get the publish status.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't use the method `IsPublished`, so I finally used `IsPublishedTo(object pubTarget)` which returns true if the page is published in a given publication target and it works.

```
foreach (PublicationTarget target in tdse.GetPublicationTargets())
{
    TDSItems listPage = SGroup.GetItems(ItemType.ItemTypePage);

    foreach (Page newPage in listPage)
    {
        if (newPage.IsPublishedTo(target) != false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

By using method `IsPublished` of class `PublishEngine` with parameters `Page` and `PublicationTarget`, you can find the publish status

```
public void Transform(Engine engine, Package package) {
    Item pageItem = package.GetByType(ContentType.Page);
    Page page = engine.GetObject(pageItem.GetAsSource().GetValue("ID")) as Page;
    PublicationTarget pubTarget = new PublicationTarget(new TcmUri("tcm:0-123-65537"), engine.GetSession());
    bool isPublished = PublishEngine.IsPublished(page, pubTarget);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to add a little more background information? I would like to know how to do this, but I'm not fully understanding what I see here. Perhaps you have a web page reference you could provide. THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using TOM, not TOM.NET.  In this case use page.IsPublished() which returns true if the page is published to the given pub target.

Answer (score 1):

If want to be totally sure, you could use invoke a curl or make a http request from c# to check that the page is also deployed as 'page.IsPublished()' will only check if the page is flagged as published in the DB